# What is blue relation line color in phpMyAdmin means?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have used phpMyAdmin for some years now and keep ignoring this question. What is the meaning of blue relation line color in phpMyAdmin Designer screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that blue and green color of the relation lines doesn't have any special meaning. They just help differentiate one line to another when the relational table design become bit crowded.